# Ansible unarchive: doesn't reach a remote host

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I use Ansible as a provisioner for Vagrant. I have a task:

```
- name: download and unarchive redis binaries
  unarchive:
    src: "http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp"
    remote_src: True
```

but for some reasons I see an error in console when I run a `vagrant provision`:

> "failed": true, "msg": "file or module does not exist: /Users/my-username/Projects/project-name/http:/download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz"`

```
> ansible --version
ansible 2.1.2.0
```

Any ideas?

NB: look carefully for the error `http:/download`. Why is there only one backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax from your question works with Ansible 2.2.0.0 and later.

For Ansible 2.0 and 2.1 use:

```
- name: download and unarchive redis binaries
  unarchive:
    src: "http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp"
    copy: false
```

---

The double slash from your question was stripped, because the argument `src` was treated as a path to a local file (again, because old versions of Ansible required `copy: false` in addition to the URL).

Comment: but documentation says: # Unarchive a file that needs to be downloaded (added in 2.0)

Comment: is it a bug? should I create an issue in ansible bug tracker?

Comment: at least of the documentation.

Comment: ok. Updated the ansible. It looks like the initial task works now